# Change all Image folders in Lightroom 4.3 at once

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-4

In my last catalog my photos directory was //192.0.2.77/Photos

After re-installing Lightroom 4.3 some time later that has changed to //SERVER/Photos

How can I change all sub-folder directories at once without having to "find missing photos"   for each folder in photos directory? I my case that would be 11 since I have them organised by year. My NAS name will change from time to time in the future and I don't want to have to do it 11 times each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1

Use a top-level folder!

[Here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/675702) is a solution. Have an additional root folder `//SERVER/Photos/Photos/` and then run `find missing photos` on that. If you don't want to do it permanently, you can move the photos from `//SERVER/Photos/` to `//SERVER/Photos/Photos/`. Then run the command, then move them back.

## Solution 2

Make sure that the server does not change the mount point or it's network address.

This solution is a bit dependent on what your "SERVER" is. I don't know your situation so the following are a few different cases that might apply for you.

- For NFS you have control over your local mount point, so set that to something fixed and update the configuration when your server moves.
- For direct network connections (like 192.0.2.77) you can either configure your router so that it gives your server always the same IP or just set the IP-address manually (on the router or on the server, router is safer for your configuration).
  ** create a route so you type `ping myserver` and this is redirected to ´ping 192.0.2.77`. You can do this on your local machine, or on the router (that goes towards adding extra DNS entries). [Using machinename.local with Macs and Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150617/how-to-use-host-names-rather-than-ip-addresses-on-home-network)

Comment: Ca you elaborate on how that would look like exactly? I mean my //SERVER/Photos folder should be the top-level folder.

Comment: Could you maybe add a quote from the website that contains the relevant information? In case the website you link to dies or something.

Comment: It seems crazy if it's not possible to change the folder directory like you can with the sub-folder. I really don't want to have directories like "//SERVER/Photos/Photos/2013"...

Comment: @DominicM I updated my response, if you could give more details how //SERVER/... changes, and what your server is, I can be a bit more specific. Thanks!

Comment: That is unfortunate that lightroom doesn't have such a basic feature. For now I will just run find missing photos 11 times and next time will try to keep root path the same. Thanks.